# Android app does not connect via socket.io

Tags: node.js, android-studio

Android app does not connect via socket.io, but via browser everything is fine. If I access via browser http://localhost:3000, it works, but when I run the android app nothing happens and there is no error message either. Note: I am using nodejs.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.security.myapplication;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Socket socket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //I created a ddns domain for external access directing to the nodejs 
        server port 3000
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://my_domain_ddns:3000");
            socket.connect();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);    

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));    

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');    

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.html');
});    

io.on('connection', socket => {

    console.log(`Socket conectado: ${socket.id}`);

});

server.listen(3000);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-with, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Chat</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="chat">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Digite seu usuario">
        <div class="messages"></div>
        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem">
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Fazendo a conexao do front com o socket -->
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        var socket = io('http://my_domain_ddns:3000');
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have corrected the url in index.html
var socket = io('http://my_domain_ddns:3000');

Comment: `localhost` is the Android device. Use the IP address of the machine running your NodeJS server.

Comment: I tried, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Change localhost in your android by the public IP of your router.

Do a port forwarding from your router to your server.

Check that your server has the port where you do your forwarding is open.

This video  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfSLxs40sIw) give more explanation.

Comment: I did exactly that, but still no success.I can access outside my network using "my domain ddns:3000", I can see the index.html, but I don't get the message "socket connected: id" in the terminal. On android I also tried the external ip and also the ddns domain, but without success.

Comment: It worked fine using the browser via "my domain ddns:3000", but if I access from android I don't get "socket connected: id" in the terminal.

Comment: Did you give the permission to use internet in the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) ? Did you try to do a http request to check your internet connection ?

Comment: Yes, I have the internet permission.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found another way that worked.

```
private void initiateSocketConnection() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(SERVER_PATH).build();
        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, new SocketListener());

   }
```

build.grade

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
```

Comment: nobody will look for your question asked in an answer - [Use this button when you want to ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)